# How to decode JavaScript stack trace form minified code on the server?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, stack-trace, source-maps

I have a client side application written in AngularJS which communicates through API with back end written in PHP. To log JavaScript errors to the server I use approach similar to the one described by Ben Nadel (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-logging-client-side-errors-with-angularjs-and-stacktrace-js.htm).

The problem is that all my JS code is minified so my stack traces logged to the server look like this:

```
  TypeError: undefined is not a function : new <anonymous>@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:11:21574
  e@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:2:295
  Object.f [as instantiate]@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:2:410
  {anonymous}()@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:2:18043
  link@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:5:14050
  q@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:2:10396
  h@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:2:6417
  {anonymous}()@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:2:6040
  E.d@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:2:6889
  n@http://exmaple.com/assets/js/dist/all.min.js?v=1409233767682885224:2:8873
```

Is there a way to decode them to the actual code traces? (I do have source maps generated)

I'm looking for solution either in PHP or NodeJS.

Comment: [Use your source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Comment: Here a client side solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33772721/1108919